# Does mongodb provide for querying sub-document collections to find parent documents?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am in the process of learning node.js and mongodb. At the recommendation of many tutorials I am making use of mongoose to help with interacting with mongo. To complicate matters I have a significant RDMS background and am doing my best to fight my mind's desire to see mongodb through a SQL lense.

Right now I am struggling with the concept of querying subdocuments. I have figured out how to query for a parent document based on a subdocument's property, but cannot figure out how to query for all parent documents (regardless of type) by directly querying child documents. To illustrate I have the following contrived example schemas:

```
// subdocument
var CategorySchema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true }
});

var IpSchema = new Schema({
  ip_address: { type: String, required: true, index: true }
  ,categories: [CategorySchema]
});

var DomainSchema = new Schema({
  domain_name: { type: String, required: true, index: true }
  ,categories: [CategorySchema]
});

var ip = mongoose.model('Ip', IpSchema);
var domain = mongoose.model('Domain', DomainSchema);
var category = mongoose.model('Category', CategorySchema);
```

The above schema embeds a subdocument array of categories in each stored domain and ip document. Making it easy to retrieve domains and ips ***separately*** based on a category name, but difficult to retrieve all domains and ips associated with a particular category in a single shot. The below code outlines why I believe this:

```
category.find(function (err, tcs) {
    console.log(tcs); // contains an empty set because no categories stored here
});

ip.find({ 'categories.name' : req.params.category }, function(err, ips) {
    console.log(ips); // contains all parent documents w/ subdocument name
});

domain.find({ 'categories.name' : req.params.category }, function(err, ips) {
    console.log(ips); // contains all parent documents w/ subdocument name
});
```

Now I could combine the results of the above queries, but that seems potentially brittle-- assuming that I reuse categories on an ever increasing number of documents. Does that leave me storing the category and then embedding a reference via a category id? That seems like it would increase churn when writing for the sake of optimizing for reads. Unfortunately my Googlefu has failed me in locating any tutorials / best practices for tagging schemes. It could also be that I am overly complicating things.

What's the best way to retrieve disparate parent documents based on a shared subdocument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK a mongo query must run against exactly one collection. This is not a mongoose fact, but a fact of mongodb itself. Given this fact, you have a few possible designs you could try. Each will have different trade-offs, so you need to understand the queries that will be important for your application and choose accordingly

**1)** Store both IPs and Domains in a single collection but with each document having a `type` property and corresponding properties.

Mongoose is not really set up to facilitate this usage pattern. Mongoose works best if the majority of your collections hold homogeneous documents. That's also true of mongodb itself, but less so. Not recommended, but not out of the question if your usage pattern really needs this.

**2)** Run the same query against multiple collections in parallel. I have some code to do this below. It's a fairly nasty hack into the internals of `Mongoose.Query`, but it works.

.

```
var _                 = require('underscore');
var async             = require('async');
function multiModelFind(query, models, outerCallback) {
  var queries = _.map(models, function (Model) {
    var otheModelQuery = new Query();
    var state = _.pick(query,
      '_conditions',
      '_fields',
      '_updateArg',
      'op',
      'options',
      'safe'
   );
    state.model = Model;
    _.extend(otheModelQuery, state);
    return otheModelQuery;
  });
  async.map(queries, function (query, callback) {
    query.exec(callback);
  }, function (error, models) {
    outerCallback(error, _.flatten(models));
  });
}
```

Sample usage:

```
var query = IP.find({"categories.name": "foo");
multiModelfind(query, [IP, Domain], function (error, ipsAndDomains) {/*...*/});
```

I think this is viable for a small number of collections, but more than a handful and you'll probably need to move to option 3.

**3)**  Created a `Categorized` collection with the schema having one named property for each collection that is an ObjectId with a mongoose `ref` and use `.populate()` to load the "joined" record. This is pretty much a straight analog to a join table in a relational database.

```
{
    category: {type: ObjectId, ref: 'Category'},
    ip: {type: ObjectId, ref 'IP'},
    domain: {type: ObjectId, ref 'Domain'},
}
```

For each record in `Categorized` only 2 of those properties will actually be non-null, and you'll do a `.populate('ip').populate('domain')` on each query. There will be 1 query for the `Categorized` collection and 1 index query by `_id` for each matched document. You could also just store the name of the category directly if it's just a keyword tag and then you wouldn't need to first look up the ObjectId for the category by name.

Comment: Option 3 seems the most logical. Obviously mongo allows for this usage pattern, but am I violating a principle by using it this way?

Comment: Nope. Neither a relational database nor a document database is a perfect fit for every use case. I think the community as a whole is coming to the realization that large complex modern apps will need to be backed by several different database engines, each one handling the use cases where it excels. This isn't the ideal use case for either document-oriented or relational databases, but it's workable in each. There may be a different NoSQL database out there that handles this more efficiently than mongodb. Not sure.